# Extract a part of address in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn, nltk

I am new to machine learning and python. I have a dataset that has an address column with

"Mankhurd mhada, Zakir Hussain Nagar, Mankhurd, Mumbai" addresses.

I want to keep just the Mankhurd part of the address. A single word like "Mankhurd" or 2 words like "Mankhur west" determining the area.

I would really appreciate help on how to extract a certain part of the text using python.

Thank You

Comment: using split() you can probably do what you want

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
string="Mankhurd mhada" 
parse=string.split(' ')[0]
print(parse)
```

output

```
Mankhurd
```

Comment: you are welcome.if my answer is suitable then you can accept and upvote

Answer (score 0):

str.split() function in python return a list of parts of the string split based on the parameters you passed to the split() function.

```
l="Mankhurd mhada, Zakir Hussain Nagar, Mankhurd, Mumbai".split(',')
name=l[0]
print(name)
>>Mankhurd mhada
```